# Git: undo rollback of uncommited changes

Tags: git, phpstorm, revert

I am trying to figure out how to undo a git rollback of uncommitted changes.

The scenario: I had several uncommitted changes on a branch, realized I forgot to create a new branch to develop the new feature, copied the current branch to the new feature branch, forgot to commit the changes on the new branch, went back to the original branch and did a git rollback to remove all the uncommitted changes. This also removed all the uncommitted changes on my new feature branch.

Obviously, I do not have a commit history to revert back to as none of the changes were commited.

Am I totally screwed? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to go into the Local History in PhpStorm and revert the changes. Phew!

Comment: As these were uncommited changes it would not have been possible to retrieve them with Git. You can thank your IDE :)

Comment: That was a close one. Saved a lot of work. Going back to the terminal, too easy to do something not intended with the right click context menu.

Answer (score 0):

for webstorm:
mouse right click on the folder that its files
rollback action was made

click "local history"

click "show history"

mouse right click on the "deleting files" row

click "revert"